# How to display the next item

Tags: vba, outlook

How to open outlook inbox every mail by macro and it is really helpful but I want to open only one mail at one time and when I close first mail then I want to hit macro again to open next mail like (1,2,3,4)?

Please help me

Answer what I have:

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub LoopThruEmails()
    'open outlook inbox mail by vba
    Dim i As Long
    Dim InboxItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim thisEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set InboxItems = GetItems(GetNS(GetOutlookApp), olFolderInbox)
     ' assume there are inbox items
    For i = 1 To InboxItems.Count
        If TypeName(InboxItems.Item(i)) = "MailItem" Then ' it's an email
            Set thisEmail = InboxItems.Item(i)
            thisEmail.Display
            Sleep (5000) ' wait 5 seconds
            thisEmail.Close olDiscard
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
Function GetOutlookApp() As Outlook.Application
     ' returns reference to native Application object
    Set GetOutlookApp = Outlook.Application
End Function
Function GetNS(ByRef app As Outlook.Application) As Outlook.Namespace
    Set GetNS = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
End Function
Function GetItems(olNS As Outlook.Namespace, folder As OlDefaultFolders) As Outlook.Items
    Set GetItems = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(folder).Items
End Function
```

Above mentioned code help me but it will open all mails after 5 second difference, but I really want to open only one at a time and next mail will be open when first mail is closed difference between mails may me 10 minute or may be 1 hours so please suggest

how to move from one mail to other?

Comment: Please provide a suitable title for your question.

Comment: I don't understand what you want but surely you can see the comment in your code: `wait 5 seconds`. Extend that to what you want it to be and perhaps put another one after the `thisEmail.Close olDiscard` line of you want it to wait after you close the email.

Comment: I Appreciate your help but I want creat a button witch open one mail at one time and when I run macro again then it will open second inbox mail without loop?

Comment: Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub LoopThruEmails()
    'open outlook inbox mail by vba
    Dim i As Long
    Dim InboxItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim thisEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set InboxItems = GetItems(GetNS(GetOutlookApp), olFolderInbox)
     ' assume there are inbox items
    i = 1
    
            If TypeName(InboxItems.item(i)) = "MailItem" Then ' it's an email
            Set thisEmail = InboxItems.item(i)
      
           thisEmail.Display
            
        End If
        'thisEmail.Close olDiscard
      

    
     i = i + 1
     
End Sub

Comment: i = 1
     If TypeName(InboxItems.item(i)) = "MailItem" Then ' it's an email
            Set thisEmail = InboxItems.item(i)
      
        End If
                i = i + 1
     End Sub    
I did some changes in above mentioned code and now code can open one mail at a time but when I want to run macro again macro opening same first mail again and again. so please suggest how I can open second mail when I run it again. Please help me.

Comment: Why not understand the code in the "answer" that you "got" so that you can *modify* the code without hoping that someone else will create another answer for you to get?

Answer (score 0):

> but I really want to open only one at a time and next mail will be open when first mail is closed

A  minor changes to your code should do the trick

Remove the following line

```
Sleep (5000) ' wait 5 seconds
thisEmail.Close olDiscard
```

And add **`True`** next to **`.Display`**

Example

```
For i = 1 To InboxItems.Count
    If TypeName(InboxItems.Item(i)) = "MailItem" Then ' it's an email
        Set thisEmail = InboxItems.Item(i)
        thisEmail.Display True
    End If
Next i
```

Once your done reading just close it and it will open the next mail Item